# Representing a ray as a union of closed rays in the integers

Tags: real-analysis

IS a ray $(2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{N}$ represnetable as a union of closed rays in $\mathbb{N}$: That is, can we write

$$ (2, \infty) = \bigcup_{n >2} [n, \infty ) $$

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See that, since we're considering rays in $\mathbb{N}$:

$(2,\infty) = [3,\infty)$, which is clearly a piece of your union.